# How can I reset the lower 4 bits of the char variable?

Tags: c++, bit

I got some problems with understanding of how to lower n bits of a char variable

Is it correct to use value << 4 for doing it?
I was thinking about something like

`value | 0x0F` or `value & 0xF0`

Comment: Try both. What are the expected and actual outcomes? Neither of the above expressions reset anything, they compute new values.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you have a `char value;` defined somewhere:

Since you want to set the 4 lower bits of `value` to zero, you need to `AND` those bits with zero, while keeping the other bits as they were (`1 & 1 == 1`, `0 & 1 == 0`):

```cpp
value = value & 0xF0;
```

or shorter

```cpp
value &= 0xF0;
```

Visual help :

```
+--------------+------------------+
| value        | a b c d _ _ _ _  |
| 0xF0         | 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0  |
| ------------ | ---------------- |
| value & 0xF0 | a b c d 0 0 0 0  |
+--------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `value` is an 8-bit `char`:

`value | 0x0F` returns a new value with the high 4 bits preserved and the low 4 bits set to 1s.

```
   xxxxyyyy
OR 00001111
   --------
   xxxx1111
```

`value & 0xF0` returns a new value with the high 4 bits preserved and the low 4 bits set to 0s.

```
    xxxxyyyy
AND 11110000
    --------
    xxxx0000
```

`value << 4` returns a new value where all of the bits have been shifted 4 places to the left, thus the old high 4 bits are discarded, the old low 4 bits are now the new high 4 bits, and the new low 4 bits are 0s.

```
    xxxxyyyy
LSH 4
    --------
    yyyy0000
```